# jQuery UI dialog closes on enter in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I open my dialog with a button then I place my cursor in a input field and presses enter my dialog closes and this line is inserted to the address bar:

[image: Address bar]

jQuery:

```
$('#dialog').load("form-incident.php").dialog({
    title: "Add Incident",
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 800,
    modal:true,
    position: ['center', 'top+50'],
    buttons: {
        Add: function(){
             $.ajax({
                url     : 'save.php',
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : $('form').serialize(),
                context: $(this),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result === "true") {
                        alert('Incident has been added successfully');
                    } else {
                        alert('ERROR: Cannot insert data to MySQL table');
                    }
                    window.location.reload();
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                },
                error   : function(){
                    alert('ERROR: Check database connection');
                }
            });
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

form-incident.php:

```
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
    Project:
    <select name="project" id="project">
        <option value="test">Test</option>
    </select><br><br>
    Incident:<br> <textarea name="incident" id="incident" style="resize:none; width: 100%;" rows="14" cols="94"></textarea>
</form>
```

How can I fix the problem so the dialog box does not close but still reacts to enter if there was some suggestions from earlier where the form was filled out?

Comment: Without seeing the rendered markup that form-incident.php is returning, I can't say for sure. But, I'm guessing that includes a form (with a method of `get` since you're seeing querystring values added to your URL). All browsers automatically submit the form if an input has focus and the user presses enter. And if the form is set to submit to itself, when it's submitted, it reloads the page. You could handle the submit event and call preventDefault() on it. But I'm not sure what you mean by "but still reacts to enter if there was some suggestions from earlier where the form was filled out".

Comment: @Elezar Thanks for your response, if i call preventDefault() on submit event dialog closes still and query string is inserted to the address bar. I have also tried to set a keyCode event but then i can't use enter if there is any suggetions when I should fill out my input field.

Comment: Okay, there's something else going on here. You don't have a submit button inside that form, so pressing Enter shouldn't even submit it. It does still seem like a form submission though, since the only other way I could think that Enter would cause a navigation is via explicit code. Is there maybe another form element somewhere on the page, that the entire dialog is inside of?

Comment: In my jQuery code i have a function called add, it submits my form with Ajax when i press the add button. But still it closes my dialog when i press enter inside a input field. No there isn't any other form elements at my page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I forgot that implicit submission will still happen if there is only a single input element in the form, even if there isn't a submit button.

So, it looks like the problem is happening from the form being submitted. But in that case, calling `preventDefault()` on the submit even will fix it.

I threw together a fiddle with your code snippets from above, and was able to reproduce the problem. Once I put in the `preventDefault()`, it stopped happening. Please check it out, and see how it differs from your live code.

https://jsfiddle.net/elezar/u0sfx22p/2/

Comment: It works with `preventDefault()` but if I load the form from another file it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, yeah. You'd have to handle the submit event and call `preventDefault()` on each page that includes the form. Alternatively, you could add the code to do so to the page that the form is on. That will make it work everywhere it's included, but it will also mean that you can't submit any form on any page where it's included. You can get around that by giving this specific form an ID, and then binding to the `submit` event on just it. See my [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elezar/u0sfx22p/4/) for an example.